# Why am I getting "TypeError: x.map is not a function" in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a json object as a prop to a child component and then parse it using map(), but I'm getting the error "TypeError: x.map is not a function". But this error occurs only in the child component.

This is the function I'm using to get the data:

```
export function Texts(){
    const [allTexts, setAllTexts] = useState([])

    async function fetchTexts (){
        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-texts/texts/`)
        const jsonResponse = await response.json()
        setAllTexts(jsonResponse)
        jsonResponse.map((text) =>{
            console.log(text.title)
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchTexts()
    },[])

    console.log(allTexts)

    return(
        <div>
            <TextsList allTexts="allTexts"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I used map() to parse and console log the data inside the function. Everything worked. But then I tried to do the same in the child component:

```
export function TextsList({allTexts}){
    return(
        <ul>
            {allTexts.map((text, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>{text.title}</li>
            })}

        </ul>
    )
}
```

But then it doesn't work. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Update 1:

I included the whole component in the entry. I should also say that when I console log 'allTexts', I get an array with all the data in the console. I don't know why it doesn't work in the child component.

Update 2:

I tried to use forEach(), but is didn't work either.

```
export function TextsList({allTexts}){
const result = [];
allTexts.forEach((text, index) => {
  result.push(<li key={index}>{text.title}</li>);
})
return(
    <ul>
        {result}
    </ul>
)
```

I got the error "TypeError: allTexts.forEach is not a function".

Update 3:

I found the problem. It turned out I was using quotes instead of curly brackets. It should be:

```
<TextsList allTexts={allTexts}/>
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more comprehensive component code example such that we can follow the entire chain from `fetchTexts` to where you are mapping it in the `TextList` component?

Comment: Is the 'allTexts' a HTMLcollection?

Comment: Same is 'allTexts' an array type value after all?

Comment: I included all the component. There are only these two components in the app so far.

Comment: Change props to this -> `<TextsList allTexts={allTexts}/>`

Comment: Now it's working. It was a very silly mistake. Thank you Amir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS i see from your code i believe the problem with main component as you passing alltexts as string only try the one below:

```
return(
    <div>
        <TextsList allTexts={allTexts}/>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try it:

```
export function TextsList({allTexts}){
const result = [];
allTexts.forEach((text, index) => {
  result.push(<li key={index}>{text.title}</li>);
})
return(
    <ul>
        {result}
    </ul>
)
```

}

Comment: I tried it. Now I got "TypeError: allTexts.forEach is not a function".

Comment: @AdrianoLazzaretti if thing.map isn't a function, and thing.forEach isn't a function, then you're going to have to revisit your assumption that thing is an array.